# CMake how to include header files so that they can be used with angle brackets?

Tags: cmake, operating-system

I am trying to use CMake for the MIT JOS Operating system project - http://repo.or.cz/mit-jos.git/tree or https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2016/jos.git

Here is the directory structure

```
lab
- .bochsrc
- CODING
- GNUmakefile
- boot
- conf
- fs
- grade.sh
+ inc
    - assert.h
    - elf.h
    - error.h
    - kbdreg.h
    - memlayout.h
    - mmu.h
    - stab.h
    - stdarg.h
    - stdio.h
    - string.h
    - types.h
    - x86.h
- kern
- lib
- mergedep.pl
- user
- CMakeLists.txt
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` under the `lab` folder (i.e. the project folder) looks like

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
    project(lab)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

    set(SOURCE_FILES
            boot/main.c
            fs/test.c
            kern/console.c
            kern/console.h
            kern/entrypgdir.c
            kern/init.c
            kern/kdebug.c
            kern/kdebug.h
            kern/monitor.c
            kern/monitor.h
            kern/printf.c
            lib/printfmt.c
            lib/readline.c
            lib/string.c
            user/sendpage.c)

    add_executable(lab ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

How can I include the header files under `inc` so that the source files can still include them using `#include <inc/types.h>` etc. rather than `#include "../inc/types.h"` ?

Comment: Judging from your folder tree, I would guess that whoever created it wanted you to add `inc` as include folder, and use `#include <mmu.h>` instead of `#include <inc/mmu.h>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you need to add an include directory for your target with [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/target_include_directories.html), for example (at the end of your CMakeLists.txt):

```
target_include_directories(lab PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} )
```

As for the difference between angle brackets and quotes when using `#include`, generally you use angle brackets only for 'system' header files (such as the C/C++ standard headers), and quotes for user supplied header (see [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)).

Comment: I tried adding `target_include_directories(lab PRIVATE inc)` to the end of `CMakeLists.txt` under `lab` directory. I still see the same kind of error `fatal error: 'inc/mmu.h' file not found #include <inc/mmu.h>`. Do I need a `CMakeLists.txt` under the `inc` directory? If so what should it contain?

Comment: @srgsanky: It is root source directory (`lab` in you case) in which the header file can be reffered as `inc/mmu.h`. So your need to include this directory instead: `target_include_directories(lab PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})`.

Comment: I don't agree with your distinction between `""` and `<>`. It is very common to use `<>` also for non-system header, especially if you have a library with a set of header files that contain the public API of the library. Then, you would put the public headers into a folder named for example `include` and `target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC include)` so that the include folder is automatically forwarded to anyone who links to your library.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev and MuertoExcobito. Adding target_include_directories(lab PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}) to the end of the CMake file solved the problem. CLion shows no error now.